# Azure Data factory trigger: Pipeline has to trigger every December on second Friday from end of the month

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-triggers

A pipeline has to trigger every December on second Friday from the end of the month.
I am trying to do this using scheduled trigger of ADF [See Trigger Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgQcS.png) by using,

- Start date of Dec 1st 2021
- Recurrence of 12 months
- No end date
- Advanced recurrence option of weekdays with occurrance as -2 and day as Friday.

```
 "name": "Dec_Last_But_One_Friday",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "runtimeState": "Stopped",
        "pipelines": [
            {
                "pipelineReference": {
                    "referenceName": "pipeline_test_triggers",
                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "ScheduleTrigger",
        "typeProperties": {
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Month",
                "interval": 12,
                "startTime": "2021-12-01T14:24:00Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC",
                "schedule": {
                    "monthlyOccurrences": [
                        {
                            "day": "Friday",
                            "occurrence": -2
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

Is this right way? how do I know it will be definitely trigger every year, the Second Friday from the end of the December month. Is there a way to see the future schedules in ADF?

Thank you!

Comment: It seems that there is no way to view the future execution plan of the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

[Viewing future ADF schedule](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/29432), this feature does not currently exist in Data Factory V2 at this time.

Due to advanced recurrence options are not perfect, we'd better check once a year.

[image]